# How to send email to two different email address in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send an email to two different email address using codeigniter email library.

```
$mail_array = array($email_address, 'example@yahoo.com');
$this->email->to($mail_array);
```

I have created an array which contains two email address.

The problem here is that the mail is sent only to one email address which is $email_address and not the other.

Can you guys help me on this.

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter?

Comment: @Meathanjay Codeigniter 3

Comment: Does it work with comma seperated string?

Comment: @SandeepPariyar Did you tried to `print_r()` $mail_array to see hold value in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is just fine but as `to` method accept an `array` or comma separated string, try change to comma separated string:

```
$this->email->to("$email_address, example@yahoo.com");
```

*Note:* Make you using real email instead of `example@yahoo.com` and see the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=email) in case you missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$mail_array = array($email_address, 'example@yahoo.com');
foreach($mail_array as $email) {
    $this->email->to($email);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add second email to CC like,

```
$this->email->cc('email@email.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

In **CodeIgniter**, sending email is not only simple, but you can configure it on the fly or set your preferences in a config file.

> **$this->email->to()**
>
> *Sets the email address(s) of the recipient(s). Can be a single e-mail,
>   a comma-delimited list or an array:*
>
> $this->email->to('someone@example.com');
>
> $this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
>
> $this->email->to(
>           array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com')  );

For more reference see this link - http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#class-reference

Hope this will help you !!